# Swift documentation of a class's methods

Tags: ios, swift

Elementary question: how do I just find what a class's methods are in the Swift Documentation?  I'm specifically trying to find what kinds of methods I can use to position a UIView other than .center, which is what this tutorial I'm looking at uses.  Tons of info, but is there just a plain list of the methods for this class somewhere?

Comment: In this case though, you might want to look for more information about 'auto-layout' as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I personally find Apple's documentation pretty annoying, but it answers your question: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/index.html

Choose language 'Swift' and click the 'On This Page' menu, near the top.

Comment: Oh thanks, that is exactly what I need, I may have never found that, I'll look up auto-layout also.